# Golang - Нахождение struct в map и возвращение struct из функции

Tags: golang

Есть такой вопрос:
можно ли каким-то образом возвращать struct и хранить эти struct в map:

Вот как решается эта задача на Python:

```
def find(number):
    packets = {10101: SomeClass}
    return packets[number]
```

И вот как я попытался решить ее в Go:

```golang
func find(req int) (Cds) { // Уже не помню, как расшифровывается Cds, но это struct
    packets := map[int]Cds {
        10101: Test.Cds,
    }
    for i, n := range packets {
        if req == i {
            return n
        }
    }
}
```

Есть ли какой-то способ сделать это?
UPD Код с Cds:

```
type Cds struct {
    initial_bytes []byte
    testvar string
}

func (self Cds) Funcinit(initial_bytes []byte) {
    self.initial_bytes = initial_bytes
}
func (class Cds) Decode() (Cds) {
    class.testvar = "Testing the test"
}
```

Comment: cdsVal, exists := packets[number] и [пример проверки](https://golang-blog.blogspot.com/2020/01/map-golang.html) на существование значения по ключу.

Comment: @DanielProtopopov возникают вопросы именно касательно возвращения cds функцией и добавление cds в packets. А за код спасибо, писал относительно давно

Comment: Какие именно вопросы возникают? В чем проблема написанного метода `find`? Он должен быть вполне рабочим.

Comment: @u_mulder Необходимо поместить struct в map ({10101: SampleStruct}), а потом вернуть его (какой тип указывать при определении функции?)

Comment: Ну так вот же указан тип - `map[int]Cds`. Если хочешь передавать мапу как аргумент в функцию `find` - то будет как-то так: `func find(req int, cdsmap map[int]Cds) (Cds)`

Comment: @u_mulder Проблема в том, что cds этих много ({10101: cdsone, 10102: cdstwo}) и находятся они в разных файлах, потому выбивается ошибка undefined: Cds

Comment: И что за ошибка? И что значит "cds этих много"? Как и на что это влияет?

Comment: undefined: Cds.

Comment: Ну а нужные импорты есть? Я смотрю у тебя в методе `Test.Cds` - то есть "`Cds` из пакета `Test`". Можешь так дальше и писать: `func find(req int, cdsmap map[int]Test.Cds) (Test.Cds)`

Comment: @u_mulder Cds этот далеко не один, потому такое не сработает, если бы такая вещь работала, то можно было бы просто взять этот самый cds и использовать без каких-либо функций

Comment: Что значит "не один"? Откуда другие? Это одинаково названные классы в разных пакетах или что?

Comment: Да, названы одинаково

Comment: Ну тогда имеет смысл либо создать интерфейс и заставить все Cds его имплементить, тогда можно использовать что-то типа `func find(req int, cdsmap map[int]CdsInterface) (CdsInterface)` или крайний случай - использовать пустой интерфейс в качестве типа: `func find(req int, cdsmap map[int]interface{}) (interface{})`.